# Working on a children hovering the father

Tags: html, css

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/pzfqT/) code should works, but in fact the span is not displayed :

```
<a class='linkz' href="#">
    <span style='display:none;'>span </span>
    link
</a>

.linkz:hover span
{
    display:block;
}
```

What I'd like to do is to display the span when I hover the link.
Why it fails? Is it not a valid CSS(2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `display:none` is set as an inline style. Inline styles will always take precedence, even over an element's (or its parent's) hover state.

If you can move the inline style into the stylesheet, it will work:

```
.linkz span
{
    display:none;
}

.linkz:hover span
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Damn, you are right! I should also put display:block !important; ;) Thanks

Comment: Well, OK, you do have to put `!important` if you can't touch the inline style. But the best solution is to move it out of the HTML and into the stylesheet, where you won't have to use `!important`...